# VS2015 removing a file on linux from windows program

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2015

We have a server on windows, but it has a network drive which is actually on a linux server. The Program has to delete a file at the same location with the same name (signals), it works ok when those files are on local drive, but when running on the network drive, it will sometime not delete the file, and even worse, the functions will return that everything went ok(meaning the file is deleted). I tried with `remove`, `_unlink`, `DeleteFileA` , the problem still persists,sometime completely at random it won't be deleted and it will stay like this.

The code is really simple:

```
bool File::Delete()
{
   if(isFile() && exist())
   {
        return DeleteFileA(filename.c_str()) != 0 ? true : false;
   }
   else 
       return false;
}
```

This will always return true even if the file is not removed, if for example it would not have permission it should fail(and fail each time, not at random), could someone give me an idea ? I ran out of options :(

**Edit:**
Thanks to @ExcessPhase, it seems like moveFile actually detects an error, so renaming before deleting can detect a problem "ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND".

Other things : This random problem can only happen when the files are created from linux server. If I create them from windows, they will always be deleted. Even more: If I have a file that the program cannot delete, and I create another file next to it from Windows, the program will detect and delete the one it could not delete before.

**Edit2:** Closer to answer: filename `test` and `TEST` in linux is different, while in Windows it's the same. The problem seems to appear at random when the case don't match. But I'm not sure since it's so random.

Comment: Is there file available to delete from remote drive from command line or with file explorer tool? Are you check the file and drive access permissions? Check file existance is work around for no errors result for fail.

Comment: it might be that somebody has the file open -- not necessary via Samba but directly under LINUX. I'm having the same problem when moving a just created .dll file -- with Samba the MoveFile system call fails telling me that somebody else has the file open as far as I remember (or permission denied).

Comment: try to replace DeleteFile() with MoveFile()&DeleteFile(). First move the file to a new name (simply with a dot in appended to the file name) and then try to delete the new file name.

Comment: @ExcessPhase your hint with moveFile seems to work, at least the program is throwing an error now :) It return error code 2, it seems like "ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" error, which is strange because the file is there and the delete doesn't return an error.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is with Samba service on Linux, which implements the SMB protocol for Windows. `DeleteFile` function just requests the SMB server (**Server** service on Windows) to delete a file. The success is returned by Samba.

Comment: It seems to be the case, as moving the file detects an error. Edited my Question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something more higher level like boost file system, or [std::experimental::filesystem::remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/remove)